# Error: "useInkathon must be used within a UseInkathonProvider" in React component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, rollup

I'm building Next.js project with React component library that depends on another library called useInkathon. I've used Rollup to build the package code and published the library to npm. However, when I was trying to use this library in my project, I encounter the following error:
**`Error: useInkathon must be used within a UseInkathonProvider`**

I've wrapped my project in a `UseInkathonProvider` component, as shown below:

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { UseInkathonProvider, shibuya } from '@scio-labs/use-inkathon'
import { PolKitProvider } from 'polconnect'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UseInkathonProvider appName='kabugu test' defaultChain={shibuya}>
      <PolKitProvider theme={{ theme: "light", Radius: "large" }}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PolKitProvider>
    </UseInkathonProvider>
  )
}
```

The **`PolkitProvider`**  is  my  library which depends on `UseInkathonProvider`
I've tested removing my package and using the context in the `index.js` page and it worked without any error.

It is my first time building NPM package and here is how I built it.

I created a components code and I installed Rollup and executed `yarn build`, then Rollup generated a dist folder then I published dist folder to NPM.

I tried wrapping up my project within `UseInkathonProvider` and I expected it  to work but it throws `Error: useInkathon must be used within a UseInkathonProvider`